# Multiline comment missing. at heredoc

Tags: node.js, heredoc

I used ejs and heredoc to compile xml files :

```
const ejs = require('ejs');
const heredoc = require('heredoc');

var tpl = heredoc(function(){/*
  <xml>
  <ToUserName><![CDATA[<%= toUserName %>]]></ToUserName>
  <FromUserName><![CDATA[<%= fromUserName %>]]></FromUserName>
  ....
  </xml>
*/});
```

however,after using jslint and compiling by babel,it becomes like this :

```
var ejs=require("ejs"),heredoc=require("heredoc"),
tpl=heredoc(function(){});
```

the content in heredoc was missing. **It seems that the compiler regards the code inside as comments.**

Does anyone know how to solve this ?

Comment: The code inside the function IS a comment. You'd have to configure your transpiler to _not_ exclude comments.

Comment: Thanks for Ted Nyberg's  nice tip, I got it!